# Containing a script

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

OK, so I have a quite odd application that is loading a js file which in turn updates the DOM of my page.

The js file is pretty much loading a view.

The problem I have is that it is not properly contained and is modifying the entire DOM (both the head and body for example)

So what I would like to keep this contained into one element. Is this possible without the use of iframes? and how bad would it be to use iframes?

is it perhaps possible to solve somehow with a shadow dom even if I can't modify the loaded js file?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not, unfortunately.

You could try and hack around things by monkey-patching in a new global `document`/`window` objects before loading the script, depending on how it does its thing, but nothing's guaranteed.